# How to get and set a value for a key in JSON file?

Tags: java, json, plist, samba

I am working with Java and Samba and Currently I have a file called `file.plist` that contains a json text that use `()`, `=` and `;` like this:

```
{
    "sites" = (
        {
            "sitename" = "default";
            "blackList" = (
                {
                    "NAME" = "SQL";
                },
                {
                    "NAME" = "CMD";
                }
            );
        }
    )
}
```

From Java I want to read the value of the key "blackList" and also I need to set a new value for that key in the same format, but this JSON is distinct because uses `() = ;` instead of `[] : ,` 
Exists any way or library to work with this JSON format?
I clarify that the File format is not `.json`, is `.plist`

Comment: the file is not in the standardized plist-format, as that could be parsed with an xml parser. Would it be possible to just replace characters so that the file would be in JSON format?

Comment: I am working automating an application, the file is a configuration file that the application uses to setup some settings, the application uses the file as is with that format, Maybe the standard of the application is use file settings so, inside a .plist file because exist other .plist files that contains xml code.
I need to read the value for that Key and Set a new Value with the same format

Comment: Stating it as the inverse of what @Palle said, a valid standard plist-format file is _not_ JSON - it does look similar to JSON but it won't parse as such. A clue is your statement "but this JSON is distinct because uses () = ; instead of [] :" ...  Your question seems to assume JSON, which this is not, so you may want to start again with a new question.

Comment: There are a variety of tools that convert PLIST XML to JSON; is the file content shown in your question the output from one of those? It may mean that the root cause of the problem is actually related to that conversion (and resolving the issue would produce valid JSON).